# How to convert data frame columns values into an array without loop

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,10,11,14], 'B':[2,3,3,5]})
```

It looks like this:

```
    A   B
0   10  2
1   10  3
2   11  3
3   14  5
```

I want to convert to this, with A as the row index, and store B's values inside the array or matrix:

```
10   2  3
11   3
14   5
```

Is there python way of doing this without looking in each row in data frame df?

many thanks

Comment: B's values should be stored in individual columns in the new array/dataframe/matrix, for future comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('A')
```

Then you can (for instance) get the mean of the grouped version by:

```
df.groupby('A').mean()
```

which result in:

```
      B
A      
10  2.5
11  3.0
14  5.0
```

Comment: I don't want the mean or sum etc, i want their actual values shown in different columns.